# Connect to a SQL Server database using Windows Authentication from a UNIX server

Tags: sql-server, unix, active-directory

I'm pretty sure that this is not possible, but is there a way to connect to a SQL Server database using Windows Authentication from a UNIX server?  The name "Windows Authentication" makes it seem that this would not be possible, but I just need to make sure.

(And don't say, "Why don't they just switch it to SQL Server Authentication?", this is obviously the solution but I need to be able to tell someone that there's no way that the Windows Authentication way will work.)

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue? We are encountering a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Kerberos Authentication](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/security/kerberos/default.mspx) in a mixed environment? (I've never implemented this but I believe it is possible by setting up 'trusts')

[Enabling Interoperability with Kerberos Clients and Servers Running Other Operating Systems](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737074%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I've worked a bit with Kerberos before - it can be a bit fiddly to set up correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html

Reading this article under "Authentication" I have the impression that the referred ODBC driver can be used with Windows Authentication